# Visualsearch - input textbox is not working on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am unable to enter input text in the visual search facets. For example I have a field Order ID, for this I want to give input text box for user to enter id manually not by selecting the drop-down value.But when the user enters the ID value and click on search button its not getting the value until unless user clicks enter button.Means Input text box is working only with enter keyword.How can I make it work on search button click also.

Here I am changed the code in visualsearch.js to capture the data once editing of textbox is done.But its working only when user ciclick two times outside of the textbox.

```
 deferDisableEdit: function () {
        this.flags.canClose = true;
        _.delay(_.bind(function () {
            if (this.flags.canClose && !this.box.is(':focus') &&
                this.modes.editing == 'is' && this.modes.selected != 'is') {
                this.disableEdit();
                parseCollection(this.app.searchQuery, false);


            }
        }, this), 250);
    },
```

Comment: What is `visualsearch.js`? is it part of some known framework/library?

Comment: @TJ https://documentcloud.github.io/visualsearch/